# PSCredential Overload Error

Tags: powershell, credentials

In powershell I want to use the username and password which are stored in $uname, $pass. These are actually read from a file and is stored in $uname and $pass, each time the script executes. I have tried like

```
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $uname,$pass
```

But the error is

```
new-object : Cannot find an overload for "PSCredential" and the argument count: "2".
```

I need to use these credentials for a New-PsSession later on in the script. Can someone please help at the earliest?

Comment: @@serverstackqns I do not have knowledge in this area but this Might be helpful for you https://powertoe.wordpress.com/2011/06/05/storing-passwords-to-disk-in-powershell-with-machine-based-encryption/

Comment: @PathumAnjana:Thanks, but the password stored in the file is in plain text format. Please refer this question to know about my file content structure:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29559282/powershell-to-read-some-strings-from-each-line

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You will have to convert your plaintext password to a secure string first:

```
$password=$pass|ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential("$uname@domain.tld",$password)
```

Comment: It should be noted that, while this works and is correct, it directly contradicts http://stackoverflow.com/a/23004997/2496266